# Using jQuery plugins (e.g. jquery-highlight) in Aurelia CLI

Tags: jquery, aurelia

I often run into issues trying to get jQuery plugins to work with Aurelia CLI.

Example: jQuery Highlight
https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-highlight

In aurelia.json I have

```
{
            "name": "jquery-highlight",
            "path": "../node_modules/jquery-highlight",
            "main": "jquery.highlight",
            "deps": [
              "jquery"
            ]
          }
```

And in my code I have...

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import {highlight} from "jquery-highlight";
...
$('#content').highlight('lorem');
```

But I get the error

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).highlight is not a function

I have also tried adding jquery-highlight to my main.ts, and adding to prepend in aurelia.json. Feels like voodoo getting these to work!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things.

If you are using the cli already, you might want to utilize it to help you with these operations as well. If you haven't run `npm install <package_name> --save` yet, you can utilize the cli to install the package and update the `aurelia_project\aurelia.json` file. Execute the command `au install <package_name>`.

In your question, it is unclear if you have added `jquery` to your `aurelia_project\aurelia.json` as a dependency(separate from the `deps` property of your `jquery-highlight` dependency).

Here are the steps I took to get it working in a new project:

1. `au new au-jq-highlight`
2. `au install jquery-highlight`
3. `au include jquery` (this adds the dependency to the `aurelia_project\aurelia.json` file, but doesn't have to be installed separately as it is installed with jquery-highlight since that package is dependent on the jquery npm package)
4. `app.html`

   ```
   <template>
     <div id="content">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nisi odio maxime adipisci obcaecati corrupti, debitis veniam reiciendis. Id distinctio aut voluptatem ipsum neque reprehenderit placeat. Laudantium modi reprehenderit dicta provident.</div>
   </template>
   ```
5. `app.ts`

   ```
   import * as $ from "jquery";
   import "jquery-highlight";

   export class App {
     public attached() {
       $('#content').highlight('lorem');
     }
   }
   ```

To not start all over and just fix what you have, I would assume you would only need to do two things:
1. Update your `aurelia_project\aurelia.json` to have:

```
"jquery-highlight",
"jquery"
```

instead of:

```
{
   "name": "jquery-highlight",
   "path": "../node_modules/jquery-highlight",
   "main": "jquery.highlight",
   "deps": [
     "jquery"
   ]
}
```

2. In your code, change `import {highlight} from "jquery-highlight";` to `import "jquery-highlight";`

Comment: Can you explain why I didn't need the deps/jquery property? I had assumed I'd need this as the plugin had a dependency on jquery which I also had in the aurelia.json file.

Comment: Short answer, no I can't. I did try updating my project to use the deps approach and here is my guess. Adding in the deps as you had done, I believe allows you to only need import "jquery-highlight"; and not import "jquery"; I use Typescript, so if I do that, the build complains, but it still compiles and works fine. My guess is that this approach will save you the jquery import if you are using es6 instead, but I'm not 100% sure.